# Import Libraries in a Python Class Package

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, class, jupyter-notebook, package

I have created a class inside a python package. The problem is that the class uses the numpy library which is not seen when imported.
'''
import numpy as np
class NN:'''
and in the init class I wrote
'''
from net.NN import NN
'''
but when I import the package in my jupyter notebook
'''
from net import NN
'''
and I initialize the class it just gives me an error "No module named np"

Comment: Have you installed numpy package in jupyter's enviroment?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: `!pip install numpy` 
Run this in a code block in jupyter-notebook

Comment: yes I installed numpy. My problem is always in the package creation I think